# psql.frame_query

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone have a link to a description of all the possible inputs into psql.frame_query() for pandas?

I have a situation where I have a number of parameters psql.execute(string, con, params).  There doesn't seem to be a similar option in psql.frame_query.  Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: Where have you seen `psql.frame_query`? I can't find it.

Comment: pandas.io.sql is the psql part. frame_query() falls under that import.  I don't have any more than that.  I am fairly new.  Thanks.

Comment: I see execute, I don't see frame_query in the source :s https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py

Comment: Row 158 in the link you sent says: frame_query = read_frame

Comment: I'm looking into this, I think it should be pretty straightforward to add, hopefully I will make a pull request later today and it could end up in dev soon.

Answer (score 2):

`frame_query = read_frame` is just a function assignement. The `read_frame` function takes at least two arguments: `(sql, con)` -- where `sql` is a string.

In the version 0.10.1 of pandas, there are a few contents in the documentation about [SQL Queries](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries). It's not a full 'SQL with pandas' doc but it's a beginning.

```
sql.read_frame("SELECT * FROM table_name;", cnx)
```

I suppose you can use `frame_query` as you use `read_frame`. In the git log, I saw that the file io/sql.py changed one year ago. The function `frame_query` was renamed. I think the it was just for compatibility. It should be removed if the name of this function is not used.

`execute` returns the result of the query. `read_frame` returns the result into a DataFrame. You can also specify the `index_col` parameter as in the `read_csv` function.