# AttributeError: module 'pandas.io.sql' has no attribute 'frame_query'

Tags: python, pandas, attributes

I am trying to read a posgresql table into a python data frame using following code.

```
import psycopg2 as pg
import pandas.io.sql as psql

connection = pg.connect("dbname=BeaconDB user=admin password=root")
dataframe = psql.frame_query("SELECT * from encounters", connection)
```

But I get `AttributeError: module 'pandas.io.sql' has no attribute 'frame_query'` How can I fix this?

Comment: which version of pandas are you using.

Comment: I checked using print(pd.__version__), it's 0.18.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the pandas.io.sql source, there is no frame_query.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/sql.py

Documentation for pandas.io.sql is here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries

---

I've looked at pandas documentation from 0.12.0 to latest and the only references to `frame_query` I've found has been to its deprecation.

I found this SO answer which may address your concerns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14511960/1703772

However, if you are using pandas version ~ 0.10 when 0.18.1 is available, I have to ask **why**.

Comment: In older version of pandas frame_query() is there.

Comment: @SaikiHanee You are very welcome. I apologize if I sounded rude to you. I thought the documentation would have been more clear as well.

Comment: frame_query and read_frame have been deprecated now there is only [read_frame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_frame.html)

Answer (score 1):

Such approach is deprecated,

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.io.sql.write_frame.html

use instead:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html